# Проблема с подключением файла БД при сборке в Maven

Tags: java, база-данных, sqlite, maven

Доброго времени суток, собираю свой проект с помощью Maven и возникла проблема с получением файла БД как ресурса.
Создаю соединение таким вот образом:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        URL resorce = Model.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/libs/diplom.db");
        DbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(("jdbc:sqlite:"+resorce));
```

Но переменная  resorce = null[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно подключать файл БД.

использовал немного другой подход, который дает правильный путь к БД через сам jar файл
`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            URL c = Model.class.getClass().getResource("/libs/diplom.db");
            System.out.println(c.getPath());
            DbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+c.getPath());`

но в итоге получаю такой стэктрэйс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что diplom.db в результате сборки находится в /libs/diplom.db?

Comment: @Sergey я открыл jar файл, там имеется папка libs и файл с БД в ней